# Iterating over rows

Tags: python, pandas

Iam trying Spilt the last word of the first Column in a DataFrame i wanted it run till the 18th index only

```
[Basically iam Trying to the last word of the first column till the index where Sector is present in the second column in the attached Image][1]
   sec=18
 if df['Unnamed: 1'].str.contains('Sector').any():
                for sec, row in df.iterrows():
                    df['Top Holdings']= df['Top Holdings'].str.rsplit(' ',1).str[0]
```

Ive Tried using iterrows but using iterrows and itertuples 2 of the last words are deleted and it does not run till the 18th index

Take out the last word of the first column till the Nth index,by trying iterrows 2 of those words get deleted and it doesnot iterate till the 18th rows

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Can you create sample data with `df = pd.DataFrame({'Top Holdings':['aaa bb cc d'] * 11,
                   'Unnamed: 1':[np.nan] * 7 + ['s','d','f'] + [np.nan]})`, be free change it and add expcted output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create mask by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for replace values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Top Holdings':['aaa bb cc d'] * 11,
                   'Unnamed: 1':[np.nan] * 7 + ['s','d','f'] + [np.nan]})         
print (df)
   Top Holdings Unnamed: 1
0   aaa bb cc d        NaN
1   aaa bb cc d        NaN
2   aaa bb cc d        NaN
3   aaa bb cc d        NaN
4   aaa bb cc d        NaN
5   aaa bb cc d        NaN
6   aaa bb cc d        NaN
7   aaa bb cc d          s
8   aaa bb cc d          d
9   aaa bb cc d          f
10  aaa bb cc d        NaN

mask = df['Unnamed: 1'].isna()
df.loc[mask, 'Unnamed: 1']= df.loc[mask, 'Top Holdings'].str.rsplit(n=1).str[0]
```

Another solution with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Unnamed: 1'] = df['Unnamed: 1'].fillna(df['Top Holdings'].str.rsplit(n=1).str[0])

print (df)
   Top Holdings Unnamed: 1
0   aaa bb cc d  aaa bb cc
1   aaa bb cc d  aaa bb cc
2   aaa bb cc d  aaa bb cc
3   aaa bb cc d  aaa bb cc
4   aaa bb cc d  aaa bb cc
5   aaa bb cc d  aaa bb cc
6   aaa bb cc d  aaa bb cc
7   aaa bb cc d          s
8   aaa bb cc d          d
9   aaa bb cc d          f
10  aaa bb cc d  aaa bb cc
```